# Reflections, mirrors and photons

Tags: reflection, geometric-optics, quantum-optics

When a perpendicular ray of light hits a plane mirror, it is said that it reflects back the same path. But won't the incoming photons get affected or distorted by the reflected one?

Comment: Low energy photons do not interact, aside from interference effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Photons can even traverse a vacuum, nothing in it, so we (scientists) have a theory that says photons are a wave (like water waves) that gets transported in a field called the Electromagnetic (or EM field).  The EM field is all around us and is responsible for all EM behaviour like electric fields, magnetism, photons/light.  When 2 waves meet they superimpose (combine) but this is only temporary, the waves reemerge and travel on their way.  The photons are like waves in the EM field.

Comment: More specifically, photons are the quanta of the EM field. They can travel in a vacuum.

Answer (score 2):

Huygens had the same reasoning for why he thought light couldn't be a particle.

[image]

In modern physics, light is considered to behave as both a particle and a wave.

Comment: to clarify, waves do not interact with each other except at the wave front. So if you swing a rope at one end up and down and at the other, the waves will meet each other in the middle but continue in the direction they were going.

Comment: It can even be said light can be considered a particle or a wave, it depends on the experiment your doing and what your trying to show.  Example is a tsunami is a wave .... not really behaving like a particle ( until maybe it hits the shoreline).